# How to send HttpPost request to php script at server

Tags: php, android, json, http-post

This is php code where I want to use the HttpPost method in Android. I want to check that json object sent along with post method is matching with the data present at the database

```
if(!isset($_POST['data'])) {
    echo "FAIL1";   
    return 'false';
}

$jsonObject = $_POST['data'];
$data = json_decode($jsonObject, true);

if(!is_array($data)) {
    print_r($data);
    exit;  
    echo "FAIL2";
    return 'false';
}

$UNIQUE_ID = $data['UNIQUE_ID'];
$BAR_CODE = $data['BARCODE'];
$BATCH_CODE = $data['BATCHCODE'];

if(!isset($UNIQUE_ID) || trim($UNIQUE_ID) == '' || !isset($BAR_CODE) || trim($BAR_CODE) == '' || !isset($BATCH_CODE) || trim($BATCH_CODE) == '') {
    echo "FAIL3";
    return 'false';
}

$link = mysql_connect($db_server,$db_username,$db_pasword) or die("Can not connect to server $db_server.");

mysql_select_db("drugverifier",$link);

$query = "SELECT * FROM drugverifier where unique_id = $UNIQUE_ID AND bar_code = $BAR_CODE AND batch_code = $BATCH_CODE";
echo " TEST4";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die("Can not able to run the query ' $query ' on server $db_server.");
echo "TEST5";
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "SUCCESS6";
    echo 'true';
}
else {
    echo "FAILURE7";
    echo 'false';
}
```

my android code is:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
        try {
            j.put("BARCODE", "8904017500190");
            j.put("BATCHCODE", "220");  
            j.put("UNIQUE_ID", "9876"); 

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v("@@@@@JSONException", e.getMessage());
        }
String url = "http://www.smartcloudinfotech.com/SmartDrugVerifier/verifyBarCode.php";
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data",j.toString()));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

                 response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                 Log.v("RESPONSE",""+response.toString());
                 Toast.makeText(this, "RESPONSE in doPOST()"+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.v("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@UnsupportedEncodingException", e.getMessage());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.v("@@@@@@@@@ClientProtocolException",e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("@@@@@@@@@@IOException116", e.getMessage());
            } 

String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

when I run this program value of variable temp doesn't contains any value.
Please help me out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: It doesn't look like your Android code even compiles, are you able to run the Android code?

Comment: yes it compiled i have stripped down this code. some part may be missing like try catch block in it or something like that, is it showing compile time error..?

Comment: @NickGarvey one of my friend said that I am not getting any response may be because of value is not getting passed to the script

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `BufferedReader` to read the contents of the `HttpEntity` like this:

```
void printResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

***Edit***
When I issue a POST using Curl to your server, with `data=test`, I get no response. I think it's due to this code:

```
if(!is_array($data)) {
    print_r($data);
    exit;  
    echo "FAIL2";
    return 'false';
}
```

Firstly, if it isn't an array, you want to print the array. That makes no sense.
Secondly, you exit, and that you echo your "FAIL2".

Comment: print_r($data);
exit;

this part is written afterwards when i was not getting any response.
I'm not getting any response may be because my value is not getting passed to script

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the response wrong in Android, it is like this

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Also I am not a big PHP programmer but I believe you are reading the values wrong in PHP you are not passing a JSONArray as far as I can tell, you are passing a JSONObject. Also remove the

```
print_r($data);
exit;
```

Comment: thanks for telling me that i am not passing json array.
I have removed 
if(!is_array($data)) {
    print_r($data);
    exit;  
    echo "FAIL2";
    return 'false';
}
this part but now script is returning me "FAIL3" as response

Comment: You are trying to get the values as Arrays $UNIQUE_ID = $data['UNIQUE_ID'];
$BAR_CODE = $data['BARCODE'];
$BATCH_CODE = $data['BATCHCODE']; This will not work as it is not an array. Also try separating your checks to see which thing actually fails, so dont put to many || in your if statements, check everything individually and send a unique error, that way you will know exactly where the error is.